# When using strtotime() getting a year of 1970?

Tags: php, function, date, strtotime

when using strtotime WEEK getting a year of 1970 on week 00? I am using a big function so cant post it all on here.

I look through the weeks getting the week days.

```
    for ($weekNumber=00;$weekNumber<=$weekEnd;$weekNumber++)
{
    runTheScript($weekNumber,$month,$weekStart,$weekEnd,$link,$limit,$standardTarget,0,$year);
}
```

my result -

Week,start,end,days

49  1st Dec 2015    6th Dec 2015    6
50  7th Dec 2015    13th Dec 2015   7
51  14th Dec 2015   20th Dec 2015   7
52  21st Dec 2015   27th Dec 2015   7
53  28th Dec 2015   31st Dec 2015   4

next

00  1st Jan **1970**    3rd Jan 2016    3
01  4th Jan 2016    10th Jan 2016   7
02  11th Jan 2016   17th Jan 2016   7
03  18th Jan 2016   24th Jan 2016   7
04  25th Jan 2016   31st Jan 2016   7

how I set the weeks

```
$weekStart  = date('W',strtotime($year . '-' . $month. '-01'));#$_REQUEST['start'];
$weekEnd    = date('W',strtotime($year . '-' . $month. '-'.date('t',strtotime($year . '-' . $month. '-01'))));#$_REQUEST['end'];
#if ($weekStart > $weekEnd) $weekStart = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no week 00.  Week 53 of last year was Dec 28 (Monday).  The next week is week 01 Jan 4 (Monday).  You should change your loop to start at weekNumber=01 and change the "greater than or equal-to" to just "greater than"

```
for ($weekNumber=1;$weekNumber<$weekEnd;$weekNumber++)
```

Comment: get rid of that `0`.

Comment: Hi @user5554551 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: this did not change a thing sorry

Comment: result - 01 4th Jan 2016 10th Jan 2016

Comment: week 00 gives me  1st Jan 1970 3rd Jan 2016

Comment: I am a little confused.  From your post I thought you wanted to get rid of the 1970 date.  In order to do so you need to remove the week 00.  The week numbers start at 1 and not 0.